# iPhone ring notification on the computer

Tags: iphone, caller-id

Is there a way with Bluetooth or WiFi or something that will display on my mac mini's screen that there is an incoming phone call or SMS and who its from with possibly a photo?

### Edit

I'm currently on a non-jailbroken phone, so would be most interested in solutions that would work a non-jailbroken phone. On the other hand... if the only solution (seamless preferably - ie the phone talks to the computer, not through a 3rd party server out in the internet someplace) is with a jailbroken phone, this would be a reason for me to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to do that directly with a non-jailbroken iPhone.  (I would *love* to be wrong about that, though.)

You might be able to set up your phone with a third-party service to get functionality like this.  For example, using [Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice) with an app like [GrowlVoice](http://www.growlvoice.com/) ($5).  GrowlVoice can provide real-time SMS notifications, but I'm not sure about real-time call notifications.

Comment: As far as I know, it might be a problem to do something like that even with jailbreak. For one, there is no recording call apps at cydia, and there might never be. My point is: *Not everything becomes possible after jailbreaking*.

Comment: @Cawas You're absolutely right, and I hope no one reads my answer as implying that it *is* possible on a jailbroken phone.  Jailbreaking can add some powerful functionality, but it's not magic.

Comment: I sure didn't misread it then! I wanted to add it explicitly to your answer given Justin's edit about jailbreaking. ;)